# Align two divs in one line but they are not in a same element?

Tags: html, css, dom, styles

I write an example here : https://jsfiddle.net/1631pndx/2/

The two elements belongs to two different div. But I want to show them in one line. And not changing other elements. Without JavaScript, Just via CSS, how to do this?

```css
.container_1,
.container_2,
.container_3 {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container_2 {
  border: solid 2px gray;
}

.container_3 {
  border: solid 2px chocolate;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_1">
  <h3> 1st element </h3>
</div>
<div class="container_2">
  <p> some other elements</p>
  <div class="container_3">
    <p> some other elements</p>
    <h3>2nd element</h3>
    <h4>[The 1st element should in here]</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want `container_1` to be where it says `[The 1st element should be in here]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be extremely difficult (maybe impossible), and error-prone, if the content of each element is dynamic.

In the case you've outlined, the content is relatively fixed. If that's the case we can use `position: absolute` with fixed `top` and `left` properties. Something like this:

```css
.container_1,
.container_2,
.container_3 {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  border: solid 2px lightblue;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container_1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 148px;
  left: 32px;
  width: calc(100% - 88px);
}

.container_2 {
  border: solid 2px gray;
}

.container_3 {
  border: solid 2px chocolate;
  min-height: 310px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_1">
  <h3> 1st element </h3>
</div>
<div class="container_2">
  <p> some other elements</p>
  <div class="container_3">
    <p> some other elements</p>
    <h3>2nd element</h3>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Again, if the content is in any way dynamic, meaning it's height is different than in the example above, the various `bottom` and `min-height` properties would need to be adjusted.

Comment: Emmm, thx for your help. My content is generated by back-end. So I am going to change that.